# How to return from async loops in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

When using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async/) library for flow control, specifically async.forEach how do you properly perform a callback in case when you need to skip a specific item.

Example:

```
async.forEach(bigCollection, function(item, callback) {

    if(skipThis) {
        return callback();
        // OR BELLOW IS BETTER??
        //return process.nextTick(callback);
    }

    db.query(query, callback);

}, callback);
```

In case that I don't use `process.nextTick(callback)` do I risk running into stack overflow if the bigCollection is too big? And in case that I do use `process.nextTick(callback)` do I anyhow sabotage my code?

I have got into habit of doing it the `process.nextTick(callback)` way, however I am not so sure it's a good practice to do so.

Comment: Stack overflow? Why would you run into that? I don't see a reason why first solution would cause that and second not. On the other hand if your collection is **really** big, then stop thinking about semi-solutions and just partition it into smaller pieces and process piece by piece (you can for example wrap everything into `async.series` and run `async.forEach` in every piece).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that without nextTick it's ok.

```
async.forEach(bigCollection, function(item, callback) {
    if(skipThis) {
        return callback();
    }
    db.query(query, callback);
}, callback);
```

If bigCollection is too big, then you will get the overflow before you come into the loop.